# How to iterate over Criteria generated List?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a method that returns all of `Article`s from database with this code:

```
public static List getAllArticles(){
    Session se=openSession();
    List li=se.createCriteria(Article.class).list();
    se.close();
    return li;
}
```

but when I want to use for-each on its result as this:

```
for(Article a :Boss.getAllArticles()){
          //      
   }
```

this error shown:

> incompatible types: Object cannot converted to `Article`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics to make this simpler. Your `getAllArticles` can return a list of `Article` objects. It would look like this:

```
public static List<Article> getAllArticles(){
    Session se=openSession();
    List<Article> li= (List<Article>)(se.createCriteria(Article.class).list());
    se.close();
    return li;
}
```

Then you should be able to iterate over it using the loop you showed:

```
   for(Article a : Boss.getAllArticles()){
          //      
   }
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, as it avoid unnecessary casting.

Comment: Sorry but just wanted to know that - `List<Article> li= (List<Article>)(se.createCriteria(Article.class).list());` isn't this also a casting ?

Comment: Yeah it is, you need to cast as the `list()` method returns a non parameterised `List` object. For what its worth I think your answer is fine too!

Comment: I didn't notice that answer also have casting and actually these two answers are the same and according to time of answering, I finally select this answer because of its submit time. I also up voted any correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use your `List` as generic type. then iterate your list, it does not require to cast your object.

```
List<Article> li=(List<Article>)se.createCriteria(Article.class).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make changes as under -

```
return (List<Article>)li; 
and public static List<Article> getAllArticles(){}
```

OR iterate thru Object, simple.

Comment: why cast, when you can use generics?

Comment: Agree @kostja, but was thinking of quick and easy solution, considering O.P.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work out using this also.

```
List<Article > articleValueList = new ArrayList<Article >();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Article.class);
articleValueList = (List<Article>) criteria.list();
```

you can iterate this `articleValueList` for fetching the values from the datatbase.